# Is sed run as a different user?

Tags: permissions, sed, root, busybox

I have a `sed` script that changes some content in `/etc/shadow`. The actual change isn't important, I will put it just as an example:

```
root@device:~ sed -i 's/root:\(.*\):0:0/root:\1:10:0/' /etc/shadow
sed: can't create temp file '/etc/passwdH5HWP7': Permission denied
```

As the output shows, there seems to be some permission error, but I am running the command as **`root`**.

The `sed` being used is from `BusyBox v1.22.1` on an embedded distribution.

If I try the example in the home folder there is no error. Also, I can edit `/etc/shadow` normally via a text editor.

Is `sed` creating files as a nonroot user?

Comment: It looks like you are updating `/etc/passwd` there instead of `/etc/shadow`

Comment: is / writable ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is probably that `/` (containing `/etc`) is a read only filesystem, but has a symlink for `/etc/shadow`, `/etc/passwd`, and other dynamic files that lands on a read-write filesystem.

This will allow you to edit the `shadow` and `passwd` files directly. The `sed -i` fails because its implementation doesn't actually update in place. Rather, it creates a temporary file and writes the changes to that, and then replaced the original file with the temporary copy. The error message you are seeing says that `sed` can't write the (temporary) file `/etc/passwdH5HWP7`.

Solution? Either don't use `-i` and control the temporary file's location yourself, or provide the `-i` flag with a filename. In both cases you need to provide a filename in a location with read-write access.

Comment: +1, but wouldn't it be simpler to remount `/` read-write before attempting the change?

Comment: @roaima Great observation! I can't, even manually, create new files in `/etc`. However everything is mounted with `rw`. Peculiarly `/etc/shadow` isn't a symlink.
But that's a different issue, you've answered my question. :)

Comment: @Anthon having seen the weirdness that a QNAP does to its root filesystem I didn't want to assume that `/` was supposed to be mounted rw.